# Pigeonhole Principle for functional values

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

*Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer co-efficients. If $f(x)=2$ for three distinct integers, then for no integer $x$, can $f(x)$ be $3$. Prove.*

Let $a,b,c$ be three distinct integers such that $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=2$. Let $x$ be any integer, then if $f(x)=1+1+1$, for some $x$, then $f(x)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)+f(c)}{2}$. But how do we conclude that no such $x$ exists? How do we use the Pigeonhole Principle in this case? What are the pigeonholes and what are pigeons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the three integers are $a,b,c$.  Then $$p(x)=f(x)-2=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)q(x)$$

where $q(x)$ is again a polynomial with integer coefficients.  We seek to prove that $p(n)$ can never be $1$ (for integer $n$).

Suppose, to the contrary, that we had such an $n$.  Then $$(n-a)(n-b)(n-c)q(n)=1$$

But $n-a,n-b,n-c$ are all integers and at least one of them is $\neq \pm 1$.  That integer would be a divisor of $1$, an absurdity.

Comment: Thank you. A very crisp and beautiful solution...